# Prove that there exists a normal extension $F/\mathbb{Q}$ with $G(F/\mathbb{Q}) \cong\mathbb{Z}_{5}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, galois-theory

> Prove that there exists a normal extension $F/\mathbb{Q}$ with
>   $G(F/\mathbb{Q}) \cong\mathbb{Z}_{5}$.

I tried to solve this problem by thinking about a polynomial which has a splitting field of order five. But I don't know how to do it. Please help me to figure it out and solve this problem.

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $K=\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$, where $\zeta$ is a primitive $11$th root of unity. Then $K$ is a Galois extension of degree $\phi(11)=10$, with
$$ \mathrm{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q})\simeq \big(\mathbb{Z}/11\mathbb{Z}\big)^{\times}\simeq \mathbb{Z}/10\mathbb{Z}$$

Let $F$ be the subfield of $K$ fixed by the unique element of $\mathrm{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q})$ of order two. Then $[F:\mathbb{Q}]=5$ and 
$$\mathrm{Gal}(F/\mathbb{Q})\simeq \mathrm{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q})/\mathrm{Gal}(K/F)\simeq \mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$$

It turns out that the element of $\mathrm{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q})$ of order $2$ can be identified with complex conjugation, hence $F=\mathbb{Q}(\zeta+\zeta^{-1})$.

Comment: Zounds +1 You beat me to it...  I was just about to hit 'post.'

Comment: Just for fun, take this sledge-hammer to crack a nut : a celebrated theorem of Shafarevich asserts that any solvable group can be realized as a Galois group over Q .